# Column selection with mouse drag using Python/Tkinter Text function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am developing a specialized text editor for a company. I am developing in Python 3.7.4 and I'm using Tkinter. One of the features I would like to develop is to select a range of columns/rows by dragging the mouse pointer from a starting point. If you're familiar with Notepad++, it is equivalent to their Alt + mouse drag feature. I've included a short video demonstrating this feature in Notepad++. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEDURCPTrHo&feature=youtu.be

I have not found a similar keystroke combination in Tkinter that allows this within a Text box. I am familiar with most elements of the Text method, and know how to determine row/column index, selection range, insert/delete, bbox attributes, etc. And I also know how to bind mouse events (click, move, release). And finally I am aware of the notion of monospace fonts and calculating row/column for the mouse event x/y coordinates. I'm just wondering if anybody has written any code to do this, or knows of a Tkinter Text method feature that I may be overlooking.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Using [Tkinter.Text.bbox-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.bbox-method) with your start/end mouse position, you should be able to compute the range to markup.

Comment: Thanks @stovfl - that's the way I'm leaning at this point. I just haven't quite figured out yet how to highlight the selected area. Hoping somebody might have some code out there that already does this!

Comment: Relevant [`[python][tkinter] [text] highlight`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+%5Btext%5D+highlight)